# ImageView Duplication of dynamically created imageview occured on Refreshing the layout on recyclerview

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have different viewholders in Recyclerview and one of them is Multiple images view. Multiple images view is nothing but A linear layout under a Horiontal Scrollview containing dynamically created Image views. Image is loaded using glide. It works fine on first load. But when the Recycler view is refreshed there is duplication of images from the previous posts. I also used Glide Clear method but it is not working either.

This is the `OnBindViewHolder` method:

```
{
    if (!(viewHolder is AdapterHolders.PostMultiImagesViewHolder holder))
        return;

    if (item.PostData.PhotoMulti?.Count > 4 || item.PostData.PhotoAlbum?.Count > 4)
    {

            var imagesList = item.PostData.PhotoMulti ?? item.PostData.PhotoAlbum;

        foreach ( var img in imagesList)
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(holder.ItemView.Context);

            imageView.SetPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            imageView.SetOnClickListener(holder);
            holder.layout.AddView(imageView);
            FullGlideRequestBuilder.Load(img.Image).Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.ImagePlacholder).FitCenter().Error(Resource.Drawable.ImagePlacholder).Into(imageView);
            ImageViewList.Add(imageView);
        }
    }

    break;
```

This is the `OnCreateViewHolder` method:

```
case (int)PostModelType.MultiImages:
{
   itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Post_Content_MultiImages_Layout, parent, false);
   var vh = new AdapterHolders.PostMultiImagesViewHolder(itemView, this, PostClickListener);
   Console.WriteLine("WoLog: NativePostAdapter / OnCreateViewHolder  >> " + (JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis() - startTime)  + " PostModelType = MultiImages" + viewType);
   return vh;
}
```

This is `OnViewRecycled` method:

```
else if (holder is AdapterHolders.PostMultiImagesViewHolder viewHolder12)
{
    foreach (ImageView img in ImageViewList)
    {
        //viewHolder12.layout.GetChildAt(img.Id);
        Glide.With(ActivityContext).Clear(img);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `ImageViewList.clear();`

before `ImageViewList.Add(imageView);`

tell me if it works